# startAt and endAt not working as expected using angularfire : 0.8.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

> Using AngularFire 8.0

Bellow is the code which uses startAt and endAt to limit the data from firebase.

```
$rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function(e, authUser){

  var queryRef = ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid);

  var queryArray = $firebase(queryRef).$asArray();

  queryArray.$loaded().then(function() {

    setCurrentUser(queryArray.$keyAt(0));

  });
});
```

The data returned should be a single element from firebase but queryArray is empty when I use console.log for debugging.

Without the use of startAt and endAt, the queryArray contains all the elements stored in the firebase.Therefore, logging **queryArray.$keyAt(0)** gives the First elements name as output. Which is as expected.

I have checked the release notes of Firebase 8.0 as well and I don't see any changes in these limiters.

Please point out if any syntactical mistake or any alternative solution which can achive the desired result.

I basically want single record from the Firebase, which is my current user , authUser is the authorized user with authUser.uid as its priority.

Following is the JSON file which is populated in the Firebase when a user registration happens.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "User A" : {
      "md5_hash" : "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930",
      "setPriority" : "simplelogin:69",
      "username" : "User A"
    },
    "User B" : {
      "md5_hash" : "2076105f6efe7c11e285add95f514b9a",
      "setPriority" : "simplelogin:70",
      "username" : "User B"
    },
    "User C" : {
      "md5_hash" : "a6d14de05d7b2c3cf4fae7ae14cfa7f3",
      "setPriority" : "simplelogin:71",
      "username" : "User C"
    }
  }
}
```

**After Edit**

Using the bellow code to get the priority:

```
queryRef.once('value', function(nameSnapshot) {
  var val = nameSnapshot.getPriority();
  console.log("Priority is: " + val );
});
```

Log output is:

> Priority is: null

The method used to add user to the Firebase is:

```
create: function (authUser, username) {
  users[username] = {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username,
    setPriority: authUser.uid
  };

users.$update(username, {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username,
    setPriority: authUser.uid
    //$priority: authUser.uid
  }).then(function () {
    setCurrentUser(username);
  });

}, // end of create method
```

Comment: The 'setPriority' key existing in your json is a bit of a flag as to the root cause. I suspect something is up with the code that sets it. Can you share the code that you use to set the priority? Also, try getting the priority explicitly to verify that it's as expected: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/getpriority.html

Comment: @JennyTong I just edited space above with the code for setting the priority. Also, I tried getting the priority. I'm new to AngularFire and Firebase ( about a week or two), so please forgive if i totally messed up in getting the priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the priority on all of your data is null. This prevents `endAt` and `startAt` from working properly.

The clue that something is up is the existence of the `setPriority` key in your data. Priority is metadata that's managed outside the normal view.

Change your user creation code to something like this:

```
create: function (authUser, username) {
  users[username] = {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username,
    .priority: authUser.uid
  };

} // end of create method
```

or this:

```
create: function (authUser, username) {
  users[username] = {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username
  };

users.$update(username, {
    md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
    username: username
  }).then(function (dataRef) {
    dataRef.setPriority(authUser.uid);
    setCurrentUser(username);
  });

} // end of create method
```

Comment: It's also possible to put priority directly into the update data by adding `.priority` as a key.

Comment: Thanks @kato.  I've integrated it into the answer.